# Using Tailwind css with single-spa applications

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, single-spa, single-spa-react

I have a collection of vite + react projects and am attempting to create a collection of single-spa Micro-frontend projects. I got the UI to be propagated as a single-spa and am currently aiming to get the imported single-spa modules' Tailwindcss to show up in the app-shell. The tailwind styling works perfectly in the project itself, but when imported in the app-shell, nothing comes through.

Has anyone been able to get Tailwind styling working for single-spa applications. Any and all help is awesome!

Comment: I wouldn't know about TailwindCSS specifically.  I did, however, create `vite-plugin-single-spa` with CSS lifecycle injection.  If the Vite build of a TailwindCSS-enabled project is a standard Vite output build, the plug-in should be able to handle your CSS just fine.